# GVim Stop at end of line with arrows

Tags: windows-7, gvim, gvimrc

When using the arrow keys in Vim on Linux, they act the same way as <kbd>h</kbd>  and <kbd>l</kbd> , stopping when the end of a line is reached. GVim on Windows doesn't do this, instead allowing the arrow keys continue past the end (or beginning) of a line and on to the next line.

Is there any way to change the arrow key behaviour and cause them to stop at the end of a line like the character navigation keys?

**NOTE:** I am not looking for a way to get to the beginning or end of a line, I realize that <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>$</kbd> do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your .vimrc file:

```
set whichwrap=b,s,h,l,<,>,~,[,]
```

to enable moving the cursor to the  next line.

And to disable (I think):

```
set whichwrap=
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Just a note for other people new to Windows GVim, the file is _vimrc for windows systems.